# Button in uitabbar doesn't push any view controllers swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode

I've added a button as a subView to tabbarcontroller to open the camera and gallery. It works fine but whenever it needs to push a view controller it does nothing. I removed the function to call the camera and gallery, and it will simply print a text in the console and it works. Meaning the button works fine but when it comes to pushing/presenting VC, nothing..

Does it something to do with the button inserted as a subview to a tab bar? It is supposed to be one of those big buttons in the middle like in Instagram.

I already made the VC to be pushed as a subclass of UITabbarcontroller. Still nothing..

Here's my code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    myPickerController.delegate = self

    let sell_image = UIImage(named: "Sell icon")

    button.setImage(sell_image, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("Sell", for: .normal)
    self.view.insertSubview(button, aboveSubview: self.tabBar)

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sellVC(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)


}
```

then the button function itself:

```
 func sellVC(sender:UIButton!) {

  print("this button prints this successfully but doesn't push the VC below")

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dummy") as! DummyViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: You're conditionally invoking `pushViewController`, this method will not be called if `self.navigationController` is nil. Are you sure this is not nil?

Comment: Hi. yes I've embedded the VC in a navigation controller. Is that what you mean?